# gitの認証情報を削除し、毎回パスワード入力を求めるようにする方法(Ubuntu環境)

Tags: git, ubuntu

環境：Ubuntu Server 20.04
現象：bashから`git push`や`git pull`を行う際、どこかにログイン情報が保存されているようでパスワード認証を求められない。認証情報を削除して毎回パスワード入力を求めるようにしたいが、どうすればいいのか分からない。

試したこと：

- `git config --global --unset credential.helper`を実行→効果なし
- `git credential-cache exit`を実行→効果なし
- `~/.git-credentials`を削除する→そもそもファイルが存在せず

Comment: `~/.gitconfig` ファイルは存在しますか？

Comment: GitHub の [HTTPS URL](https://docs.github.com/ja/get-started/getting-started-with-git/about-remote-repositories#cloning-with-https-urls) を用いた接続に関する質問、という理解で合っているでしょうか？(URL は `git remote -v` コマンドで確認できます)

Comment: @DEWA Kazuyuki
GitHubにHTTPSでログインしている状況で間違いないです。
コマンドの出力は以下のようになりました
`$ git remote -v origin  https://github.com/[githubユーザー名]/[リポジトリ名].git (fetch) origin  https://github.com/[githubユーザー名]/[リポジトリ名].git (push)`
`

Comment: @cubick 存在していましたが、ユーザー名とEメールの記述しかありませんでした。試しに削除してみましたが、動作は変わりませんでした。

Comment: ワーキングディレクトリ内で `git config -l --show-origin | grep credential` コマンドを実行することで認証に関する設定を出力できるかと思いますが、どんな設定が為されているでしょうか。

Comment: 出力結果は以下の通りでした `file:.git/config        credential.helper=`

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu環境におけるデフォルトのヘルパーがどう設定されているか存じませんが，[マニュアル](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitcredentials#Documentation/gitcredentials.txt-helper)によると`credential.helper`をからの文字列にすることで設定をリセットできるようです．いかがですか？

(ローカルでのみ無効化する例)

```
$ git config --local credential.helper ''
```

Comment: こちらを試してみましたが、相変わらずpush,pullともにパスワード要求されませんでした…

Answer (score 0):

リモートリポジトリでの認証形式を接続鍵認証からパスワード認証に変えればいいです

＃そのリモートマシンでパスワード認証が許可されてるのかどうかはまた別のお話